# SQL Query to find the frequency of element in a column

Tags: sql, asp.net

In a HelpDesk System I have a Table (Request) which contains a colume (Status : Open, In progress, Closed )

I want a Query to compare between the number of open requests and closed ones , Using VisualStudio Charts

I try to use this SQL Query to Count the frequency of Open and Closed Requests, 
but there was a syntax error

```
SELECT [Status] COUNT[Status] AS Frequency
FROM [RequestF] GROUP BY [Status]

 asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                           <Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="Status"  ChartType="Pie"></asp:Series>
</Series>
<ChartAreas>
    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        <AxisY>
            <LabelStyle Format="P0" />
        </AxisY>
    </asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>

                       </asp:Chart>
                       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BiomedicalSampleConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Status] COUNT[Status] AS Frequency FROM [RequestF] GROUP BY [Status] "></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You are missing a comma in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT Status,COUNT(Status) AS Frequency FROM RequestF GROUP BY Status"
```